# What are the key hyperparameters to tune in CatBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, catboost

I've used XGBoost for a long time but I'm new to CatBoost. If I wanted to run a sklearn RandomizedSearchCV, what are CatBoost's hyperparameters worthwhile including for a binary classification problem?
Just looking for a general sense for now, I know this will be problem specific to a certain degree.

Comment: Did you learn anything you would like to share here?

Answer (score -1):

I am in the middle of running a Catboost classifer and I have observed immense improvement in the F1 score by tuning the following:
n_estimators, learning_rate, depth, rsm and class_weights